# Python - call function within itself (same parameters)

Tags: python

I am calling the same function within itself.

```
base_url="www.myurl.com"
urls_1="www.myurl.com/1"
urls_2="www.myurl.com/2"
rep_1="/report1"
rep_2="/report2"

    def get_response(url, report):
      response=requests.get(url,report, headers=header)
      data=response.json()

      if (len(data))==100:
          header.update({"range":rep + str(range_from + 100) + "-" + 
          str(range_to + 100)})
          **data2=get_response(?,?)**

     else:
         return data
```

When I call the function inside, I want to use the same parameters that I used to call the outer function.(Only writing the function once)

This outer function gets called hundreds of times with all different parameters; sometimes it gets called within a for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? You are probably finding `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`? The reason why should be obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data2=get_response(url, report)

Answer (score 3):

What you're attempting is known as [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) in computer science.

```
def my_function(x,y,z): 
    something = my_function(x, y, z)
```

However, this is going to throw you into an infinite loop.
For recursion to work, you have to have a base case -- a way of stopping -- and then simplify the problem at each step.  See on-line tutorials and examples of recursion.

Comment: @Paul: Edit the code into your question; comments can't format code, which is especially important for Python.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines.  Among other things, any code needs to be in readable format: edit it into your original question, not into a comment.